# How to restart sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, restart

I'd like to know if there is an option on Sublime text to close and re open, for using after installing some plugin or in bug case..
I've been searching but I couldn't find anything... Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?  Can't you just close and open it with with red x in the corner?

Comment: Yes, I can, but being an awesome tool I though sublime had that option...

Comment: I was under the impression Sublime had such functionality after seeing the following message from SublimeLinter: "SublimeLinter has been installed or upgraded. Please restart Sublime Text.". Apparently not.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the **Restart** plugin/package in Sublime Text 2 as well as Sublime Text 3. Install it from Package Control's package install in your sublime text.

After installing Restart, simply press **F5** key or use **File > Restart** option.

**Note**: To open package control use Ctrl/Command + Shift + P.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to be more specific:                                                                                    Ctrl/Command + Shift + P>Package Control: Install Package>Search Restart>Enter

Comment: Im not seeing this Restart package when searching in PackageControl.

Comment: The package installed fine in Sublime Text 4, but it doesn't work. [This does, however](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74452976/4561887).

Answer (score 2):

### How to upgrade and restart Sublime Text from the command-line in Linux Ubuntu, with no special Sublime packages installed

I hate the idea of having to install a whole package just to "restart" Sublime.

So, here's what I do, from a regular terminal command-line. Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with Sublime Text 4:

```bash
# How to "restart" Sublime Text

# 1. kill it
pkill sublime
# 2. start it up again
subl
```

I had 6 windows open, with a bunch of tabs in each, before running `pkill`. After "restarting" sublime like this, all 6 windows were back open again, with all of their same tabs as before, just as though I had restarted my computer.

Bonus:

Restarting Sublime is required after upgrading it. So, here are my 3 commands to upgrade and restart. This assumes you already followed [the instructions here to install Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html#apt) in the first place using `apt` on Ubuntu.

```bash
# upgrade Sublime Text to the latest version
sudo apt udpate
sudo apt install sublime-text

# Now restart sublime text
pkill sublime
subl
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Restart Git repo:
[Removal of key maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnwfz.png)

After an initial install the shortcut key ,**F5**, freezes the application. As the above illustrates this is because the key bindings have been removed (why? I couldn't find any conflicts). To fix this add the following to your keymap file:

```
{"keys": ["f5"], "command": "restart"},
```

Using the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html) as a guide you can add this to the Command Palette by editing or creating a file **'file_name.sublime-commands'** anywhere under **sublime-text-3/Packages/** and adding the following to it (Use what ever value for caption you like)

```
{ "caption": "Restart", "command": "restart" }
```